# Can I repair or replace shower door?

Tags: bathroom, doors, shower

Our shower door was damaged and cannot close properly. Can I repair or replace just the door? It looks like the door is secured by three screws.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is difficult to see what exactly the issue is other than the door sagging.  Can you be more specific about what is causing the sag.  Maybe get us a pic close up.  It may be something as simple as larger screws, but with the posted pics it is hard to tell.

Comment: Has the door pulled apart at the top due to something like someone pulling or swinging on it?

Comment: The door was pulled down on which caused the spiral hing to separate at the top and bend down